# using different layouts for an entire controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, iframe, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having problems with something that should be simple.

I have two use cases...

- The user is the site directly
- The user is using an iframe from
  another site

I want to do the same thing in either case except I don't want to use the layout for my website in the case it's the iframe so I have a "plain" layout

```
layout "plain"
```

How can I dynamically assign the layout depending on the case..

ie `params[:iframe] == true`   etc.

Nothing I do seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
layout :layout_by_resource

def layout_by_resource
  if params[:iframe] == true
    'plain'
   else
    "your-main-layout"
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

How about this

```
class FramesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :decide_on_layout


  protected
  def decide_on_layout
    layout "plain" if params[:iframe] == "y"
  end

end
```

Comment: that gives me "undefined method `layout' for #<NotificationsController:0x10582c5e8>"  ;-(